# rotated tables displayed in a single page

Tags: captions, rotating, page, floatrow, sidewaystable

I need two tables rotated and shown in a single page. Code for main.tex is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning}
\tikzset{block/.style={draw,thick,text width=2cm,minimum height=1cm,align=center},
    line/.style={-latex}
}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage[boxruled,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}



\input{structure}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\endgroup


\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter1}
  \input{ch1}
\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{blue}{Bibliography}}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

Code for structure.tex is:

```
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist{nolistsep} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{243,102,25} 

%   MARGINS

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, 
    top=3cm,
    bottom=3cm, 
    inner=3.2cm, 
    outer=4.8cm, 
    headheight=14pt, 
    footskip=1.4cm, 
    headsep=10pt,
}


%   FONTS


\usepackage{avant} 
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

%   MAIN TABLE OF CONTENTS

\usepackage{titletoc} 
\contentsmargin{0cm} 
\titlecontents{part}
[0cm] 
{\addvspace{20pt}\bfseries} 
{}
{}
{}


\titlecontents{chapter}
[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{12pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} 
{\color{blue!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{blue}} 
{\color{blue}} 
{\color{blue!60}\normalsize\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} 

\titlecontents{section}
[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{3pt}\sffamily\bfseries} 
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} 
{} 
{\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} 
\titlecontents{subsection}
[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} 
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} 
{} 
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} 
\titlecontents{figure}
[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} 
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}} 
{} 
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} 
\titlecontents{table}
[1.25cm] 
{\addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small} 
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}} 
{} 
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} 

%   MINI TABLE OF CONTENTS IN PART HEADS


% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{lchapter}
[0em] % Left indentation
{\addvspace{15pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{blue}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{blue}} % Chapter number
{}
{\color{blue}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{lsection}
[0em] % Left indentation
{\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{}

% Subsection text styling (note these aren't shown by default, display them by searchings this file for tocdepth and reading the commented text)
\titlecontents{lsubsection}
[.5em] % Left indentation
{\sffamily\footnotesize} % Spacing and font options for subsections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}}
{}
{}


%   HEADERS AND FOOTERS


\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \thechapter \ #1}{}} % Styling for the current chapter in the header
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}} 

\fancyhf{} 
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage} 
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} 
%\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} 

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% Style for when a plain pagestyle is specified
    \fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
    \clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
        \hbox{}
        \vspace*{\fill}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \newpage
    \fi}


%   THEOREM STYLES

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm} % For math equations, theorems, symbols, etc
\newcommand{\intoo}[2]{\mathopen{]}#1\,;#2\mathclose{[}}
\newcommand{\ud}{\mathop{\mathrm{{}d}}\mathopen{}}
\newcommand{\intff}[2]{\mathopen{[}#1\,;#2\mathclose{]}}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\newtheorem{notation}{记号}[section]
\allowdisplaybreaks[4] 

% Boxed/framed environments
\newtheoremstyle{ocrenumbox}
{0pt}% Space above
{0pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily\color{blue}}% Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily\color{blue}\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
    \thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}---\nobreakspace#3.}} % Optional theorem note

\newtheoremstyle{blacknumex}% Theorem style name
{5pt}% Space above
{5pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% Body font
{} % Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily}% Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily{\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\nobreakspace\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
    \thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries---\nobreakspace#3.}}% Optional theorem note

\newtheoremstyle{blacknumbox} % Theorem style name
{0pt}% Space above
{0pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily}% Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
    \thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries---\nobreakspace#3.}}% Optional theorem note

% Non-boxed/non-framed environments
\newtheoremstyle{bluenum}% Theorem style name
{5pt}% Space above
{5pt}% Space below
{\normalfont}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\small\bf\sffamily\color{blue}}% Theorem head font
{\;}% Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em}% Space after theorem head
{\small\sffamily\color{blue}\thmname{#1}\nobreakspace\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{}\@upn{#2}}% Theorem text (e.g. Theorem 2.1)
    \thmnote{\nobreakspace\the\thm@notefont\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}---\nobreakspace#3.}} % Optional theorem note
\makeatother

% Defines the theorem text style for each type of theorem to one of the three styles above
\newcounter{dummy}
\numberwithin{dummy}{section}
\theoremstyle{ocrenumbox}
\newtheorem{theoremeT}[dummy]
\theoremstyle{blacknumex}
\newenvironment{prove}{\begin{proveT}}{\hfill{\tiny\ensuremath{\qedhere\blacksquare}}\end{proveT}}
\theoremstyle{blacknumbox}
\newtheorem{vocabulary}{Vocabulary}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definitionT}[section]
\theoremstyle{ocrenum}


%   DEFINITION OF COLORED BOXES


\RequirePackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed} % Required for creating the theorem, definition, exercise and corollary boxes

% Theorem box
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
    skipbelow=7pt,
    backgroundcolor=black!5,
    linecolor=blue,
    innerleftmargin=5pt,
    innerrightmargin=5pt,
    innertopmargin=5pt,
    leftmargin=0cm,
    rightmargin=0cm,
    innerbottommargin=5pt]{tBox}

% Exercise box    
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
    skipbelow=7pt,
    rightline=false,
    leftline=true,
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    backgroundcolor=blue!10,
    linecolor=blue,
    innerleftmargin=5pt,
    innerrightmargin=5pt,
    innertopmargin=5pt,
    innerbottommargin=5pt,
    leftmargin=0cm,
    rightmargin=0cm,
    linewidth=4pt]{eBox}

% Definition box
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
    skipbelow=7pt,
    rightline=false,
    leftline=true,
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    linecolor=blue,
    innerleftmargin=5pt,
    innerrightmargin=5pt,
    innertopmargin=0pt,
    leftmargin=0cm,
    rightmargin=0cm,
    linewidth=4pt,
    innerbottommargin=0pt]{dBox}

% Corollary box
\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
    skipbelow=7pt,
    rightline=false,
    leftline=true,
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    linecolor=gray,
    backgroundcolor=black!5,
    innerleftmargin=5pt,
    innerrightmargin=5pt,
    innertopmargin=5pt,
    leftmargin=0cm,
    rightmargin=0cm,
    linewidth=4pt,
    innerbottommargin=5pt]{cBox}


\newenvironment{theorem}{\begin{tBox}\begin{theoremeT}}{\end{theoremeT}\end{tBox}}
\newenvironment{exercise}{\begin{eBox}\begin{exerciseT}}{\hfill{\color{blue}\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\end{exerciseT}\end{eBox}}
\newenvironment{definition}{\begin{dBox}\begin{definitionT}}{\end{definitionT}\end{dBox}}
\newenvironment{example}{\begin{exampleT}}{\hfill{\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}\end{exampleT}}
\newenvironment{corollary}{\begin{cBox}\begin{corollaryT}}{\end{corollaryT}\end{cBox}}


\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  sorting=nyt,
  sortcites=true,
  autopunct=true,
  autolang=hyphen,
  abbreviate=false,
  backref=true,
]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}
\addbibresource{Reference.bib}


%   REMARK ENVIRONMENT
\newenvironment{remark}{\par\vspace{10pt}\small 
\begin{list}{}{
\leftmargin=35pt 
\rightmargin=25pt}\item\ignorespaces
\makebox[-2.5pt]{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\node[draw=blue!60,line width=1pt,circle,fill=blue!25,font=\sffamily\bfseries,inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt] at (-15pt,0pt){\textcolor{blue}{R}};\end{tikzpicture}} 
\advance\baselineskip -1pt}{\end{list}\vskip5pt}



%   PART HEADINGS

\newcommand{\@mypartnumtocformat}[2]{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \noindent\colorbox{blue!20}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\ecart}{\color{blue!70}\Large\sffamily\bfseries\centering#1}}\hskip\esp\colorbox{blue!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth-\ecart-\esp}{\Large\sffamily\centering#2}}%
 }

% unnumbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@myparttocformat}[1]{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \noindent\colorbox{blue!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\centering#1}}%
 }

\newlength\esp
\setlength\esp{4pt}
\newlength\ecart
\setlength\ecart{1.2cm-\esp}
\newcommand{\thepartimage}{}%
\newcommand{\partimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thepartimage}{#1}}%
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@mypartnumtocformat{\thepart}{#1}}{\partname~\thepart\ ---\ #1}}
    \else%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@myparttocformat{#1}}{#1}}%
    \fi%
    \startcontents%
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\thispagestyle{empty}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
        \node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
            \fill[blue!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);

        \node[anchor=north] at (4cm,-3.25cm){\color{blue!40}\fontsize{220}{100}\sffamily\bfseries\@Roman\c@part};
    \node[anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth-1cm,-\paperheight+1cm){\parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}{
                    \printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}%
            }};
            \node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#2}};
            \end{tikzpicture}};

   \end{tikzpicture}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@spart#1{%
\startcontents%
\phantomsection
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
        \fill[blue!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
        \node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#1}};
        \end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \noindent\protect\colorbox{blue!40}{\strut\protect\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\protect\centering #1\quad\mbox{}}}}{#1}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
\if@twoside
\if@openright
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\newpage
\fi
\fi
\if@tempswa
\twocolumn
\fi}



%   CHAPTER HEADINGS
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    chaptertitle/.style={
        text = black,
        node font = \huge\sffamily\bfseries ,
        text width = \paperwidth-\Gm@lmargin-10pt ,
        align = left
    }
}

\newif\ifusechapterimage
\usechapterimagetrue
\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}%
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]{\ifusechapterimage\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}\fi}%
\newcommand{\autodot}{.}


\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
     \iftrue
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node at (current page.north west)
        {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
            \draw[anchor=west,chaptertitle] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=blue,fill=white,fill opacity=0.7,inner sep=23pt]{\strut\makebox[44cm]{}};

   \draw[anchor=west,chaptertitle] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node {\iftrue\thechapter. \fi#1\strut};
   
            \end{tikzpicture}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \else
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.north west)
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};
        \draw[anchor=south west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=blue,fill=white,fill opacity=0.7,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
        \draw[anchor=south west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
        \end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\fi\fi\par\vspace*{270\p@}}}

\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\ifusechapterimage\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\fi};

\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin,-9cm) node [line width=2pt,rounded corners=15pt,draw=blue,fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,inner sep=15pt]{\strut\makebox[22cm]{}};
\draw[anchor=west] (\Gm@lmargin+.3cm,-9cm) node {\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{black}#1\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\vspace*{270\p@}}
\makeatother
```

Code for ch1.tex

```
The reference used here is \cite{1.1}.
\newpage

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccccc} \\
\hline
bb & $b1$ & $b2$ & $b3$ & $b4$ & $b4$ \\ \hline

bb & $b1$ & $b2$ & $b3$ & $b4$ & $b4$\\
bb & $b1$ & $b2$ & $b3$ & $b4$ & $b4$\\
bb & $b1$ & $b2$ & $b3$ & $b4$ & $b4$\\
bb & $b1$ & $b2$ & $b3$ & $b4$ & $b4$\\
bb & $b1$ & $b2$ & $b3$ & $b4$ & $b4$\\
bb & $b1$ & $b2$ & $b3$ & $b4$ & $b4$\\
bb & $b1$ & $b2$ & $b3$ & $b4$ & $b4$\\
 \hline
\label{table:4}\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{This is table 1}
 \vspace{2\baselineskip}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc} \\
\hline
aaaa (in Kg) \\ \hline
All & a1 & a2& a3 & a4 & a5 & a6 &a7 & a8\\ \hline
 $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & $7$ & $8$ & $9$\\
 $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & $7$ & $8$ & $9$\\
 $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & $7$ & $8$ & $9$\\
 $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & $7$ & $8$ & $9$\\
 $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & $7$ & $8$ & $9$\\
 $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & $7$ & $8$ & $9$\\
 $1$ & $2$ & $3$ & $4$ & $5$ & $6$ & $7$ & $8$ & $9$\\
 \hline
\label{table:5}\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{This is table 2}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

code for references.bib

```
@book{1.1,
  title={Securing critical information infrastructure: Global perspectives and practices},
  author={Sharma, Munish},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Institute for Defence Studies and Analyses}
}
```

This gives an error "`Package floatrow Error: Caption(s) lost.`" Also, caption of the first table does not appear. Can anything be done? The page before table of contents page looks weird.
Is it ok to provide the overleaf link for this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You could try using `\rawcaption{\caption{...}}`.  I'm not sure that floatrow and the caption package are even compatible. much less sidewaystable.